# How do you cause Chrome to show or hide www in address bar?

Tags: google-chrome, dns

Visit https://www.netlify.com/ in Chrome - it shows the "www" in the address bar

Visit https://www.reddit.com/ in Chrome - it does not show the "www" in the address bar. However, when you double click in the address bar the "www" is shown

Why does Chrome show the www before and after double clicking in one case, but only after double clicking in the other? How can I control whether the www is shown on my own site?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is general, but I will explain how I achieved this with Apache through a permanent redirect at the front door of the server, meaning whenever a browser knocks on the 80 port of the webserver with a request for `www.example.com`, Apache will always say, you need to go to `example.com`, then I will work with you. Meaning, no matter how hard you try, Apache will always send the browser to the non-www version of a website.

Here is the non-www example.com configuration file which then serves up the website in the DocumentRoot, `example.com.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName 1happyplace.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/...
</VirtualHost>
```

In the www version of the website configuration file, `www.example.com.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com

    Redirect permanent / https://example.com/

    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Note that the use of `http` or `https` is important depending on whether the site supports encryption, it reduces the redirects.

Comment: Hi Katie, thanks for taking the time to answer. I think you misunderstood what's happening. I'm aware of redirects, but I don't believe that's what's happening in this case. Reddit is indeed using a www in their domain. You can verify in the Chrome network inspector that it returns a 200 for www.reddit.com and does not redirect. However, Chrome does not show the www in the address bar until you double click in the address bar. This is inconsistent with the behavior for www.netlify.com for example where the www is shown. I'm unsure as to how Chrome decides whether or not to show the www

Comment: This might answer your question: https://superuser.com/questions/1333575/chrome-address-bar-no-longer-shows-protocol-or-www-subdomain

Comment: But why is it only done on some sites and not others?

Answer (score 0):

First of all this is not only related to chrome.

You can do it this way by simply redirecting-

Add this code in your .htaccess file -

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Replace  example with your domain.

Comment: I'm not talking about a redirect. Go to the pages I mentioned. Double click in the address bar so that the whole URL shows. They're both actually www URLs. It's just only showing the www before clicking on one of them. As a counter-example, if you go to digg.com and double click it does not show a www.

Comment: Yes because they are not using www in their domain, go to my site https//www.techinfoserve.com/ I have given a www link but go and visit you will not see www in the URL

Comment: Reddit is indeed using a www in their domain. You can verify in the Chrome network inspector that it returns a 200 for www.reddit.com and does not redirect